# Access attributes in controller while looping in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a loop in my view:

```
<% @deals.each do |d| %>


<% end %>
```

`Deal` and `ListItem` share the `:code` attribute.

If I wanted to count all the `list_items` that shared `:code` with a certain deal, how can I do this in the controller while iterating through the loop?

I understand it's bad form to access Models in the view correct? So that would rule out doing something like this in the loop right?:

```
<%= "#{ListItem.where(:code => d.code).count}" %>
```

Can I use a variable or some custom method to achieve this? Please let me know if I can clarify. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the models of Deal and ListItem. How are they associated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do all the calculation on the server in your controller action before rendering the view.

So in addition to gathering the `@deals`, you will also set an instance variable for the count.

```
def index
  @deals = Deals.all # or whatever your finder is

  @common_listitem_count = ListItem.where(code: @deals.pluck(:code)).count
end
```

Then just call the count instance variable in the view:

```
<%= @common_listitem_count %>
```